# pivot_longer on a mix of matrix columns and regular vector columns

Tags: r, tidyr, tibble

I have a `tibble` where some columns are matrices. Here's a toy example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat <- structure(list(id = 0:5, matrix_column = structure(c(-1.34333431222985, 
                                                            -1.54123232044003, -1.7260282725816, -1.8924463753132, -2.0376516335872, 
                                                            -2.16069643164938, -0.250406602741403, -0.287716094522968, -0.32269823315914, 
                                                            -0.354360193430544, -0.382155662949252, -0.405883260458378, 1.53709630050992, 
                                                            1.76715755374983, 1.98313378488307, 2.17881959842109, 2.35072520728221, 
                                                            2.4974704619887), .Dim = c(6L, 3L)), vector_column = c(10.453112322311, 
                                                                                                                   10.3019556236512, 10.1273409693709, 9.91474471968391, 9.65093549479026, 
                                                                                                                   9.32601906868098)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                         "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The `tibble` looks like this.

```
> dat
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     id matrix_column[,1]   [,2]  [,3] vector_column
  <int>             <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>
1     0             -1.34 -0.250  1.54         10.5 
2     1             -1.54 -0.288  1.77         10.3 
3     2             -1.73 -0.323  1.98         10.1 
4     3             -1.89 -0.354  2.18          9.91
5     4             -2.04 -0.382  2.35          9.65
6     5             -2.16 -0.406  2.50          9.33
```

If I apply `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` to the non-`id` columns, the values in `vector_column` get replicated to fill the two additional columns required to accommodate `matrix_column`.

```
dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -id, values_to = "new_column")

# A tibble: 12 x 3
      id name          new_column[,1]   [,2]  [,3]
   <int> <chr>                  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0 matrix_column          -1.34 -0.250  1.54
 2     0 vector_column          10.5  10.5   10.5 
 3     1 matrix_column          -1.54 -0.288  1.77
 4     1 vector_column          10.3  10.3   10.3 
 5     2 matrix_column          -1.73 -0.323  1.98
 6     2 vector_column          10.1  10.1   10.1 
 7     3 matrix_column          -1.89 -0.354  2.18
 8     3 vector_column           9.91  9.91   9.91
 9     4 matrix_column          -2.04 -0.382  2.35
10     4 vector_column           9.65  9.65   9.65
11     5 matrix_column          -2.16 -0.406  2.50
12     5 vector_column           9.33  9.33   9.33
```

Is there a way to have the `[,2]` and the `[,3]` columns of `new_column` to be `NA` (instead of the same value of `[,1]`) when `name` equals `vector_column`?

Something like

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
      id name          new_column[,1]   [,2]  [,3]
   <int> <chr>                  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0 matrix_column          -1.34 -0.250  1.54
 2     0 vector_column          10.5      NA    NA 
 3     1 matrix_column          -1.54 -0.288  1.77
 4     1 vector_column          10.3      NA    NA
```

My real life data have dozens of matrix columns and vector columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you continue with the format of data that you currently have (having dataframe and matrix together) you'll keep on running into trouble to work with it. I would suggest to convert the matrix into dataframe and add them as their separate columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat$matrix_column %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  bind_cols(dat %>% select(-matrix_column)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id, values_to = "new_column")

#      id name          new_column
#   <int> <chr>              <dbl>
# 1     0 X1                -1.34 
# 2     0 X2                -0.250
# 3     0 X3                 1.54 
# 4     0 vector_column     10.5  
# 5     1 X1                -1.54 
# 6     1 X2                -0.288
# 7     1 X3                 1.77 
# 8     1 vector_column     10.3  
# 9     2 X1                -1.73 
#10     2 X2                -0.323
# … with 14 more rows
```